Delete all files files in a folder three with two conditions: filename has only digits and a specific extension
thank you for your help. I look for a code to select all files in a folder three which have the filename similar to: ###.xlsx, where # is a digit. I am a newbie, and found a code that works for deleting all .xlsx in the folder three but I need to add the rule for deleting only the ones with only digits in the filename so that for example:

it does not delete a file called "44rta.xlsx"
it deletes a file called "456.xlsx".

If simpler, I can specify also the number of digits, so that it deletes all files with only three digits, for example.
This is the code I'm starting from:
import sys
import os
import glob

main_dir = (r'Folder\Path')
folders = os.listdir(main_dir)

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(main_dir):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
          source_file = os.path.join(dirname, file)
          os.remove(source_file)

It deletes all the .xlsx in the folder but it's only half of the work! I need to delete only the ones of this type: onlydigits.xlsx
Thank you!

The simplest would probably be using the re module and check your filename against a regular expression like

^\d+\.xlsx$   matches all filenames consisting of an arbiraray number of digits and .xlsx extensions
^\d{3}\.xlsx$  matches all filenames consisting of exactly 3 digits and .xlsx extensions
^\d{3,5}\.xlsx$  matches all filenames consistingof 3-5 digits and .xlsx extensions
^\d{3,}\.xlsx$  matches all filenames consistingof at least 3 digits and .xlsx extensions
^\d{,3}\.xlsx$  matches all filenames consisting of at most 3 digits and .xlsx extensions

Take one, that fits your needs best or adapt one according to your needs.
import re
import sys
import os
import glob

main_dir = (r'Folder\Path')
folders = os.listdir(main_dir)

r = re.compile(r"^\d+\.xlsx", re.I) # match caseinvariant, ie 123.xlsx and 123.XLSX

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(main_dir):
  for file in files:
    if r.match(file):  # check if the current filename matches the regualr expression
      source_file = os.path.join(dirname, file)
      os.remove(source_file)  


Woow, flowless! Super thanks

@monkeyman If that answer helped you, don't hesitate to upvote/accept it ...
